# How to use lat and long to get Place_id from Google Places

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-places-api

I'm trying to return Google reviews for an array of stores. Therefore, each store has a unique placeid which I first need to find in order to return the reviews. All the tutorials I'm seeing show me how to use `getPlace()` on an autocomplete field to get the placeid, but I just have a model with lat and long properties and need to use those to get the place id.

The example Google gives [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-placeid-finder)

`google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input).getPlace();`

is only for autocomplete. I was hoping I could use `getPlace()` and somehow plug in lat and long to return the placeid.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use the PlaceService `.nearbySearch` with you coordinates.  It will return multiple results, most likely the result you are looking for is the closest one to your input coordinates.

```
service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
var request = {
  location: searchLoc,
  radius: '50'
};
service.nearbySearch(request, function callback(results, status) {
  if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var minDistance = Number.MAX_VALUE;
    var closestMarker = null;
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      var marker = createMarker(results[i]);
      var distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(searchLoc, marker.getPosition());
      if (distance < minDistance) {
        minDistance = distance;
        closestMarker = marker;
      }
    }
    closestMarker.setMap(map);
    map.setCenter(closestMarker.getPosition());
  }
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/2vwva0m0/1/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var NeimanMarcus = new google.maps.LatLng(32.768863635112375, -117.16740846633911);
  var Nordstrom = new google.maps.LatLng(32.76856592648975, -117.1685242652893);

  service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  findNearestPlace(Nordstrom, service, map, infowindow);
  findNearestPlace(NeimanMarcus, service, map, infowindow);

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);

function findNearestPlace(searchLoc, service, map, infowindow) {
  var request = {
    location: searchLoc,
    radius: '50'
  };
  service.nearbySearch(request, function callback(results, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
      var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
      var minDistance = Number.MAX_VALUE;
      var closestMarker = null;
      for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        var marker = createMarker(results[i], map, infowindow);
        var distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(searchLoc, marker.getPosition());
        if (distance < minDistance) {
          minDistance = distance;
          closestMarker = marker;
        }
      }
      closestMarker.setMap(map);
      map.setCenter(closestMarker.getPosition());
    }
  });
}

function createMarker(place, map, infowindow) {
  var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: place.geometry.location
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
    map.setZoom(19);
    infowindow.setContent(place.name);
    infowindow.open(map, this);
  });
  return marker;
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry,places"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```